# pip upgrade impossible due to SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to upgrade pip:

`python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`

but I'm get the following message:

> Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python\lib\site-packages (23.0)
> Collecting pip
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

Does anyone know what this message means and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try `pip install certifi`

Comment: the error continue

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>pip install certifi
Collecting certifi
  Using cached certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Installing collected packages: certifi
Successfully installed certifi-2022.12.7

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\python\lib\site-packages (23.0)
Collecting pip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /packages/07/51/2c0959c5adf988c44d9e1e0d940f5b074516ecc87e96b1af25f59de9ba38/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: @luissuarez When adding or clarifying detail for your question, please edit and add to the Question do not add as a comment(s).

Comment: Are you using a proxy to access the internet? Does pip have access if so?

Answer (score 3):

The real `files.pythonhosted.org` site has a proper (current) SSL certificate from GlobalSign.

Apparently, on your machine, `pip` is seeing a connection to something else ... that has a self-signed certificate.

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Pip's attempts to connect to `files.pythonhosted.org` are being redirected by (for example) your organization's firewall.  This kind of thing happens when an organization blocks direct internet access.  Maybe ... you are supposed to configure your computer to use an organization-provided internet proxy service?
2. Someone / something is trying to snoop on your internet connections.
3. Someone / something has messed up your local network's routing in a spectacularly bad way.

IMO, 1) is the most likely explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org
```

Answer (score 1):

in my company the server is blocking the pip install. I use successfully:

```
hepython -m pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org
```

or

```
pip install <package name> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I am on a vodafone network in Spain and using PyCharm on Windows 11. When I pip install and pip upgrade (and also visit files.pythonhosted.org) it failed due to CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED in the browser the SSL cert was from 'tomcat' and self signed. ... I'm presuming vodafone has blocked files.pythonhosted.org (but not sure).

[pip install cert error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Euqq.png)

I FIXED it by updating my windows hosts file to point to the correct files.pythonhosted.org server.

BEFORE:
[ping to files.pythonhosted.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTYCS.png)

AFTER (hosts file change):
[ping to files.pythonhosted.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJmCF.png)

If you 'ping' file.pythonhosted.org via on online ping checker like https://networkappers.com/tools/ping-tool and use the ip address in the results in your hosts file that should work.

Edit your windows host file at:
%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

and add
146.75.117.63 files.pythonhosted.org

(using the ip address that you see in the online ping tool).